# Coming up with equation for word problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm going from memory here but think I have the question right...

A CEO gives out gift cards to his staff. Each gift card is $10 in value. He gives 3 to those who have been there for 3 years, 5 to those who have been there for 5 years and 10 to those who have been there for 10 years. The total is 282. There are 14 more people who have been there 5 years than there are 3 years. There are 3 more people who have been there for 10 years than 5 years. How many people have been with the company for 10 years?

I tried:

Let A=3 years, B=5 years, C=10years. Then A+B+C=282

A=B+14
C=B+3

this can give us C+11+C-3+C=282 which gives C=86 but this was the wrong answer :( and I don't know the correct answer.

Comment: Is 282 the number of gift cards handed out, or the number of people working at the company?

Comment: @JazzyMatrix I think it meant the number of gift cards handed out. That's why I had trouble with the question, I wasn't sure which interpretation was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is a little bit wrong with your recollection of the problem, unfortunately. I see two different interpretations of the question:

1. There are 282 workers in this company that have been there for either 3, 5, or 10 years.
2. The CEO gave out 282 gift cards.

Let's work through each interpretation. First, let's figure out the relationship between the number of people who have been working for different numbers of years:

- There are 14 more people who have been at the company for *five* years than there have been for *three* years. This implies that $B = A + 14$ -- not that $A = B+14$!
- There are three more people who have been at the company for ten years than for five years. You are correct in deducing that this implies $C = B+3$!

Putting this together, we have that $A = C - 17$ and $B = C - 3$. Now, let's explore the two options we have:

**Option 1:** Suppose there are 282 workers in the company, which can be broken up into groups of those who have been employees there for 3, 5, and 10 years. This tells us that $282 = A + B + C$. Plugging in the values we obtained above, we have that

$$282 = C - 17 + C - 3 + C = 3C - 20 \Rightarrow 302 = 3C \Rightarrow C = 100 + \frac{2}{3}$$

**Option 2:** Suppose the CEO gave out 282 gift cards. Then, since each person gained a gift card equal to the number of years they worked at the company, we have that $282 = 3A + 5B + 10C$ which, given our equations we got earlier, gives us

$$282 = 3(C-17) + 5(C-3) + 10C = 18C - 66 \Rightarrow 348 = 18C \Rightarrow C = 19 + \frac{1}{3}$$

As you can see, both options result in some fraction of a person working at the company. Typically in word problems we don't like to chop people up like this, so I'm assuming the value of $282$ must be off by a few.

Answer (score 0):

Let there be three set of people, A = People with 3 years of experience, B = People with 5 years of experience, C = people with 10 years of experience.

Now we give out 3 cards to people with 3 years of experience similarly for people with 5 years and 10 years of experience.

Note that A is the number of people and each person who belongs to set of People A recieves 3 cards and 282 is the total number of cards that the CEO is giving out.

So, 3*A + 5*B+ 10* C = 282

Also there are 14 more people in set B than A, so A + 14 = B  and as there are 3 more people in set C than B we have the equation C = B + 3

From these 3 equations it follows that A = 7/3, B = 49/3, C = 58/3